# Auth0 cookie is set with the auth0 url and not my domain. How do I fix it?

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, session-cookies

I know it's not due to my app code as I tested the app against someone else auth2 and it worked fine. The issue results in the cookie not being usable for my domain.

But for the life of me I cannot figure out how I messed up the auth2 config.

[Cookie:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSJZx.png)

[My auth2 config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BflqM.png)

I noticed the cookie was received back from auth2 but was 'dropped'.

I initially didn't notice the domain and spent time fixing issues due to the attributes:

- I added SSL
- Tried multiple browsers and clearing cache
- changed domain name since this is on local host

Once I noticed the domain issue I went through all of the auth2 config but I cannot find what was set wrong.